# use loop to reuse the task written in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I am writing Ansible playbooks. I generated a random string (e.g. 4M[0-9].html) and added it to the list.  I am not sure how to use the loop to generate a bunch of strings (for example 50 of them) and added to the same list ***url_list***.  Below is the code I already have.  Any help will be appreciated.

```
- name: xxx
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local

  tasks:
    - name: create an variables
      set_fact:
        url_list: []

    - name: generate random string
      vars:
        random_str: ''
      set_fact:
        random_str: "{{ random_str }}{{ item }}"
      with_items:
        - '4M'
        - "{{9 | random}}"
        - '.html'

    - name: add str to the list
      set_fact:
        url_list: "{{ url_list + [item] }}"
      with_items:
        - "{{ random_str }}"

    - name: print the random string from the list
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}"
      with_items: "{{ url_list }}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `range` in a loop (replacement for old `with_sequence` loop) to control how many times to iterate the loop.

You also do need the initial step to create a random string. It can be done as you are building the `url_list` variable.

Try this:

```
- name: xxx
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local

  tasks:
    - name: create an variables
      set_fact:
        url_list: []

    - name: add str to the list
      set_fact:
        url_list: "{{ url_list + ['4M' + (9 | random | string) + '.html'] }}"
      loop: "{{ range(0, 50) | list }}"

    - name: print the random string from the list
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ url_list }}"
```

Comment: The first task in the playbook is not necessary. Simply remove it and modify the second one to add a default value: `url_list: "{{ url_list | default([]) + ['4M' + (9 | random | string) + '.html'] }}"`